# How to chain validations together using Golang go-playground/validator?

Tags: validation, go, go-playground

I am using https://github.com/go-playground/validator for a REST API server. I am using the same struct for different endpoint with different validation requirement. For example, `/users/login` requires only `email` and `password`. However, to create a user, more information like `firstName` would be required.

So I think using struct tag to validate is not very convenient. Checking the variable as described in this [example](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/_examples/simple/main.go) seems more appropriate. However I run into two problems:

1. I am checking multiple at the same time. Is there a way to chain a series of validation together? Checking every single variable in a struct then check for error makes it harder to code and harder to read.
2. The error object is really empty. For example, checking if email is required shows only `err.Tag()` and `err.ActualTag()` as `required` and `err.Kind()` and `err.Type()` as `string` and nothing else. Does the validator provide anything that makes this a little more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ozzo-validation](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation). it uses normal programming constructs rather than error-prone struct tags to specify how data should be validated.
I recommend you to define different validation function/method for each use-case(request).

```golang
func ValidateLogin(req) {
err := validation.Validate(req.Username,
        validation.Required,       // 
        is.Email)
...
}

func ValidateRegister(req) {
...
}
```